# Command line SAPI text-to-speech to WAV/MP3

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, text-to-speech

As the title says I need to be able to create a WAV or MP3 file using SAPI on Windows XP.

I can install basically anything needed if anyone can recommend a third party application which would allow me to do this.

In terms of programming languages really only VB6 is available on the target machine (yeah...) so if anyone can recommend a way of doing it in VB6 that would be fine too.

Thanks :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498004/how-to-save-sapi-text-to-speech-to-an-audio-file-in-vbscript/20537139

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed this by implementing a quick VB app based on the VB TTS app provided in the speech SDK - was very simple.

If anyone else has this problem I'd be happy to provide the source - but it's not on this computer right now so I'll get it later.