# How to save SAPI text to speech to an audio file in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, text-to-speech, sapi

I have the following VBScript code for text to speech conversion:

```vb
Set objVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
objVoice.Speak Inputbox("Enter Text")
```

I want to save the speech to an audio file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save the SAPI output to a .WAV file as follows:

1. Create and open a .WAV file as a stream using the [`SpFileStream.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.
2. Assign this file stream to the [`SpVoice.AudioStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.

Here's an example:

```
Const SAFT48kHz16BitStereo = 39
Const SSFMCreateForWrite = 3 ' Creates file even if file exists and so destroys or overwrites the existing file

Dim oFileStream, oVoice

Set oFileStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
oFileStream.Format.Type = SAFT48kHz16BitStereo
oFileStream.Open "C:\Work\Sample.wav", SSFMCreateForWrite

Set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
Set oVoice.AudioOutputStream = oFileStream
oVoice.Speak "Hello world"

oFileStream.Close
```

Comment: In my case I needed to add `oVoice.WaitUntilDone(10000)` after `.Speak` otherwise the file would be closed immediately. I also used `oVoice.Speak "Hello world", 3`