# how to make exporting of file in hta and saving to disk

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am working on HTA App so I have made app that u can enter the text and the voice plugin is reading  but now I want  the code that can make that sound to be exported and saved to disk that is all

Comment: this is my code:<script language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
Dim width,height
width=470
height=400
self.ResizeTo width,height
End Sub
Function Listen
Dim message
message = tamsg.value
If (message = null) Then
X = MsgBox("Enter your message", 48, "Error Message")
Else
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak message
End If
End Function
</script

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save SAPI text to speech to an audio file in VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498004/how-to-save-sapi-text-to-speech-to-an-audio-file-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
Set objStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
Line="hello there"
ObjStream.Open "c:\users\HelloThere.wav", 3, vbFalse
set objVoice.AudioOutputStream = objStream
objVoice.Speak Line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**[HTA] create an MP3 sound file of typed text**](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1379667/autres-langages/general-visual-basic-6-vbscript/vbscript/hta-creer-fichier-mp3-texte-saisi-clavier/)